# Order in group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Currently I want to understand why order in group changes, even thought I 'give' it the right 'first' row.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `B` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `C` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `D` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) VALUES
(1, 1, 77, 0, 'Vasya'),
(2, 1, 77, 999, 'Masha'),
(6, 1, 77, 999, 'Clone'),
(3, 1, 88, 1, 'Natasha'),
(4, 2, 1, 1, 'Dima'),
(5, 3, 1, 1, 'Katya');
```

These two queries give the same answer:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, id FROM `test` WHERE `A`=1 AND `B`=77 ORDER BY `C` DESC

SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, D, id FROM `test` WHERE `A`=1 AND `B`=77 ORDER BY `C` DESC
```

But these two give different answers:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT A, B, C, D, id FROM `test` WHERE `A`=1 AND `B`=77 ORDER BY `C` DESC
) AS t  GROUP BY A, B


SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, D, id FROM `test` WHERE `A`=1 AND `B`=77 ORDER BY `C` DESC
) AS t  GROUP BY A, B
```

I just want to get rows with max 'C', which belong to one 'A' and one 'B'. But without 'DISTINCT'.
What am I doing wrong?

**PS**: I had to add *`A`=1* to be more particular. There is no such condition in working project, it is *not* an query to select one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `group by`, the standard practice is to put all non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause (or, if MySQL option `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled: all columns that are not functionally dependent on other columns already in the `group by` clause). Your query does not complies to this golden rule: as a consequence you are getting inconsistent results.

In MySQL 8.0, you could solve this using window functions:

```
select id, a, b, c, d
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by a, b order by c desc, id) rn
    from test t
) x
where rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, a correlated subquery can get the job done (in your use case, this might actually be more efficient than `row_number()`):

```
select t.*
from test t
where id = (
    select id 
    from test t1 
    where t1.a = t.a and t1.b = t.b 
    order by c desc, id 
    limit 1
)
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nwf1y4N6N5pGevQkSRNNon/0)**, both queries return:

```
| id  | A   | B   | C   | D       |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | ------- |
| 2   | 1   | 77  | 999 | Masha   |
| 3   | 1   | 88  | 1   | Natasha |
| 4   | 2   | 1   | 1   | Dima    |
| 5   | 3   | 1   | 1   | Katya   |
```

Comment: I've edited 'INSERT INTO' part of my question to show that your query for earlier versions returns more than one row per A/B when A/B/C are the same. Currently I can't use MySQL 8.0.

Comment: @AlexShiganov: which record would you want to return for `A = 1`, `B = 77` and `C = 999`: `'Masha'` or `'Clone'`?

Comment: any, but only one, may be dependent on id ASC.

Comment: @AlexShiganov: ok, that's clear enough. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: your new query actually works, but I don't understand what's going on there  or is it slow query. Can you explain in your answer, please?

Comment: @AlexShiganov: the subquery returns the smallest id that has the maximum value of `c` for the `a/b` tuple. This should be very efficient, especially if you have an index on `(a, b, c)`

Comment: @AlexShiganov: `order by` and `limit 1` is how we get the relevant id. You can run the subquery independently to see what it returns (for example with `t1.a = 1 and t1.b = 77`)

Comment: I understand that, we get one row with limit 1. But why 'select' returns multiple rows, though you are not using 'where id in (1, 2, 3)', you set id to exact value (limit 1)? Is this some kind of joining two equal tables on A, B, and C desc for second table?

Comment: @AlexShiganov: this is a *correlated* subquery. It returns the relevant id for values of A and B in the outer query: see the where clause of the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about a single A/B combination

```
select
      t2.*
   from
      ( select t1.A, t1.B, max( t1.id ) highestByABandID
           from test t1
             JOIN
             ( select A, B, max( C ) highestC
                  from test
                  where A = 1 and B = 77
                  group by A, B ) PQ1
                on t1.A = PQ1.A
               AND t1.B = PQ1.B
               AND t1.C = PQ1.highestC
      ) PQ
         JOIN test t2
            on PQ.A = t2.A
           AND PQ.B = t2.B
           AND PQ.highestByABandID = t2.id
```

If you want for ALL A/B combinations, just remove the inner "WHERE" clause to get all A/B combinations with their respective highest C value.  The join to the outer will pull whatever record is associated with that one instance.

Revised query.  Had to add one more nesting.  The inner-most grabs the highest "C" value for any given A/B combination.  From that, now re-join to the same test table based on only those matching A/B and the Highest "C" and grab the single most recent ID added. Now you will only have 1 per A/B combination that has the highest "C" value.  Finally, finish the join based on the matching A/B and highest "ID".

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd37ef/3)

Comment: Unfortunately the query should return no more than one row per A/B even when A/B/C are the same.

Comment: @AlexShiganov, revised query to wrap and get only a single per highest "C".  Please review.